# typo issue in php using html

Tags: php

i have this simple typo issue here i guess.
How can i resolve it?

```
<?php the_content("<br /> <span class='custom-more'>Read More: " . get_the_title('', '', false) "</span>"); ?>
```

I need to make a read more button in WordPress and i need to wrap the read more inside a span class.
I get this error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in
```

How am i supposed to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the concatenation operator  `.` between  `get_the_title` function and `</span>`

```
 <?
    php the_content("<br /> <span class='custom-more'>Read More: ".get_the_title('', '', false)."</span>"); 
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks very much :)
this solved it, i'm accepting your answer in a few min

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `concatenate (.)`

Correct code will be

```
 php the_content("<br /> <span class='custom-more'>Read More: ".get_the_title('', '', false)."</span>");
```